# Bootstrap 4.1.3 $font-family-base is ignored

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to change the default font-family in Bootstrap but my changes are ignored.

This issue is closed on the repo (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21595) but I still have the problem.

```
> bundle info bootstrap
=> bootstrap (4.1.3)
```

I have `bootstrap-custom.scss`:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.1.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

 ...
 @import "bootstrap/variables";
 ...
```

`_variables.scss`:

```
...
//== Typography
//
//## Font, line-height, and color for body text, headings, and more.

$font-family-sans-serif:  "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !default;
$font-family-serif:       Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !default;
//** Default monospace fonts for `<code>`, `<kbd>`, and `<pre>`.
$font-family-monospace:   Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace !default;
$font-family-base:        $font-family-sans-serif !default;
...
```

And I import it in `application.scss` at the top of my file:

```
@import "bootstrap-custom";
@import "variables";
```

If I try this css, that doesn't work:

```
body {
  font-family: $font-family-base;
}
```

But if I change the name of `$font-family-base` in the `_variables.scss` and use the new variable in body, it works.

Do I something wrong?

Comment: Try importing your application.scss file  after importing the bootstrap related stuff.

Comment: @Anji It's the default scss file for Rails, it should already be rendered at the end (because it loads the all files)

Comment: can you please provide a simple plunker, what you did till now.

Comment: I don't tried a lot of things, this is the default configuration, so I don't know what could I do... I have the same configuration in another project and it works perfectly

Comment: I don't have any idea on Rails configuration. If you are able to provide some inputs with your I can be able to help you.

Comment: I'm using a gem (link a component) that import Bootstrap in my application. Rails uses a file called `application.scss` where you have to import all your scss files. So I have `bootstrap-custom.scss` and `_variables.scss`. Then, these files are imported in `application.scss`. bootstrap-custom then variables.When all the files are loaded, rails renders a unique css file with every scss files imported (so I should have an error if it's a problem with the order of the imported files). Also, Rails precompiles the files so I forced the assets precompile and restart the server

Comment: I am not sure what's happening here, as per your explanation it has to work properly. I can help you by giving a quick hack. try *{ font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } in your css file, Note: It is not the good practice and use this if you have only one font(Roboto in our case) in your website.

Comment: If I'm doing this, that works @Anji. I'm going to keep it for the moment and try again to solve the problem later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I upgraded the bootstrap gem from `4.1.3` to `4.2.1`. Then, I removed `bootstrap-custom.scss` file, import the whole official `_variables.scss` file, and import bootstrap with all files.

Also, I had to import `bootstrap/functions` before variables.
Now the custom variables work.

Comment: No problem @AndreiGheorghiu but, again, because I'm not very good with the front-end, I asked to be referred more than anything else. I spent the afternoon but it's OK now. :) Good night!

Answer (score 0):

There are very fewer chances of this, but did you check the file names correctly?

From your code, it seems that custom style file name is **`bootstrap_custom.scss`** and the one which you have imported is **`bootstrap-custom`**.

See the difference of **_ (underscore)** and **- (dash/hyphen)** in file names.

Comment: Oops, not, it's just a mistake in the post, the names are correct